# Spark Stream Kafka hang at JavaStreamingContext.start, no spark job create

Tags: apache-spark, stream, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, freeze

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5
JRE:Oracle 1.8.0.144-b01
spark-streaming_2.11:2.1.0
spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0

Spark stream Kafka jar submitted by spark-submit to standalone spark cluster, and running well for a few days. But recently, we find that no new job generated for the stream, we tried to restart the job, and restart the cluster, the stream just stuck at JavaStreamingContext.start, and WAITING (on object monitor). Thread dump as below, and no error log from spark and Kafka. I wonder what spark stream is waiting for...

```
"shuffle-server-3-4" #35 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f76a0041800 nid=0x3d34 runnable [0x00007f76911e5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000f8ea3be8> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x00000000f8ee3600> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000f8ea3ae0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:760)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:401)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"shuffle-server-3-3" #34 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f76a0040800 nid=0x3d33 runnable [0x00007f76912e6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000fc2747c0> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x00000000fc2874c0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000fc2746c8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:760)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:401)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"shuffle-server-3-2" #33 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f76a003e800 nid=0x3d32 runnable [0x00007f76913e7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000fb227370> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x00000000fb2296a0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000fb227278> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:760)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:401)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5" #80 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f76a0034800 nid=0x3d31 runnable [0x00007f76916e7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000f8e8ed98> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000f8e8ed88> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000f8e7d008> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:454)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:277)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:134)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.listOffset(Fetcher.java:324)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.resetOffset(Fetcher.java:298)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.updateFetchPositions(Fetcher.java:174)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateFetchPositions(KafkaConsumer.java:1409)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:983)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.paranoidPoll(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.start(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach_quick(ParArray.scala:143)
        at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach(ParArray.scala:136)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:972)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:969)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"JobGenerator" #79 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f76a0007800 nid=0x3d30 waiting on condition [0x00007f76917e9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fe48b8d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:492)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.take(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:680)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:46)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"JobScheduler" #78 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f76a0004800 nid=0x3d2f waiting on condition [0x00007f76918ea000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fe48cb98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:492)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.take(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:680)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:46)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"streaming-start" #77 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77323a1000 nid=0x3d2e in Object.wait() [0x00007f76919ea000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:295)
        - locked <0x00000000fa037d50> (a scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:341)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:673)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask$class.sync(Tasks.scala:378)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.sync(Tasks.scala:443)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks$class.executeAndWaitResult(Tasks.scala:426)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport.executeAndWaitResult(TaskSupport.scala:56)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ExecutionContextTasks$class.executeAndWaitResult(Tasks.scala:558)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ExecutionContextTaskSupport.executeAndWaitResult(TaskSupport.scala:80)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$class.foreach(ParIterableLike.scala:463)
        at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray.foreach(ParArray.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.start(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
        - locked <0x00000000fa0380d0> (a org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.startFirstTime(JobGenerator.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.start(JobGenerator.scala:100)
        - locked <0x00000000fe48b4d0> (a org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.start(JobScheduler.scala:102)
        - locked <0x00000000fe48b170> (a org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamingContext.scala:583)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply(StreamingContext.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply(StreamingContext.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$$anon$2.run(ThreadUtils.scala:126)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"SparkListenerBus" #21 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7732291800 nid=0x3d2d waiting on condition [0x00007f7691cec000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000081c9be70> (a java.util.concurrent.Semaphore$NonfairSync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
        at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1245)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:77)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None


"Spark Context Cleaner" #74 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f773228a000 nid=0x3d2b in Object.wait() [0x00007f7691eee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
        - locked <0x00000000fe4675d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1245)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:67)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"shuffle-server-6-1" #70 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77321b5800 nid=0x3d2a runnable [0x00007f7691fef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000fa182e28> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x00000000fa1b3938> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000fa182d90> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:760)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:401)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"threadDeathWatcher-4-1" #65 daemon prio=1 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7704019800 nid=0x3d29 waiting on condition [0x00007f76932f1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Watcher.run(ThreadDeathWatcher.java:150)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"shuffle-client-1-3" #30 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f76fc006800 nid=0x3d28 runnable [0x00007f76933f2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000fd326748> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x00000000fd328838> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000fd3266a0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:760)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:401)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"shuffle-client-1-2" #29 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f770801a800 nid=0x3d27 runnable [0x00007f76934f3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000fe49d458> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x00000000fe4b02d0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000fe49d360> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:760)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:401)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"shuffle-client-1-1" #28 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7700005000 nid=0x3d26 runnable [0x00007f76935f4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000fe4b24a0> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x00000000fe4b4570> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000fe4b23a8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:760)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:401)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"appclient-registration-retry-thread" #61 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f76a800f000 nid=0x3d22 waiting on condition [0x00007f76939f8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fe4e0e28> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"driver-revive-thread" #57 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f76b0004000 nid=0x3d1e waiting on condition [0x00007f7693dfc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fe4e0450> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"dag-scheduler-event-loop" #56 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77321a5800 nid=0x3d1d waiting on condition [0x00007f7693efd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fe38ff08> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:492)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.take(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:680)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:46)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"shuffle-server-3-1" #32 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7731fea800 nid=0x3d07 runnable [0x00007f76f4863000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000fc26eeb8> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x00000000fc271470> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000fc26edb0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:760)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:401)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f773187a800 nid=0x3ce5 runnable [0x00007f76f5d6b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x0000000081bb6f80> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x0000000081bb6f70> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x0000000081bb6e48> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:454)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:277)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:229)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:134)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f773000d800 nid=0x3ca7 in Object.wait() [0x00007f7736da7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1252)
        - locked <0x00000000fe463ad0> (a org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$$anon$2)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1326)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.runInNewThread(ThreadUtils.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
        - locked <0x0000000081c9ea00> (a java.lang.Object)
        - locked <0x0000000081f19c80> (a org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:556)
        at com.ccb.iomp.appmon.analysis.statistic.processor.StatisticProcessor.start(StatisticProcessor.java:780)
        at com.ccb.iomp.appmon.analysis.statistic.TranLogStatisticApp.main(TranLogStatisticApp.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the following stack trace:

```
"ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5" #80 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f76a0034800 nid=0x3d31 runnable [0x00007f76916e7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000f8e8ed98> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000f8e8ed88> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000f8e7d008> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:454)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:277)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:134)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.listOffset(Fetcher.java:324)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.resetOffset(Fetcher.java:298)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.updateFetchPositions(Fetcher.java:174)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateFetchPositions(KafkaConsumer.java:1409)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:983)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.paranoidPoll(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.start(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
```

It stuck at fetching offsets from Kafka. You should check your Kafka cluster.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We have restart the Kafka cluster, the stream works!  It's strange that logstash consume the same topic as spark stream and worked fine before the restart~

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently too. In my case, the problem was that there was only one Kafka broker running in the dev environment, but, `offsets.topic.replication.factor` was set to 2. Try setting it to 1. This isn't a good idea in production but may workaround the issue where you just need 1 broker for testing.